# How do I check if an object exists at a certain index of an NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

For instance, how could I verify if there is an item at the index 3?

The objects in the `NSArray` are instantiated from the class "Animal."

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well, since `NSMutableArray` has to hold non-nil objects, as long as the array is big enough, you know there's *something* at index `i`:

```
if ([myArray count] > 3) {
    id myObj = [myArray objectAtIndex:3];
    ...
}
```

If you needed to check something elsek, like say make sure it didn't have a reference to the NSNull singleton, you could then check

```
if (myObj != [NSNull null]) ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Since there can be no 'gaps' in a NSMutableArray's storage, if your index is less than `[array count]`, you can be certain an object is present at that index.

Comment: They could be null, though, right (but that is easy to check, too)?

Comment: No NULLs (or nils) in the array, though there can be NSNull objects.

Answer (score -2):

try this code

```
for(int j = 0; j < [yourArray count]; j++)
{
    if(obj isKindOfClass:[Animal class]]) {
        return
    }
}
```